# How to correctly detect neighbour cells

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

As a learning project, I'm writing a simple logical game where the user has html canvas grid where he needs to connect same-colored squares.

I'm stuck at detecting neighbour cell's properties(its colour) and if condition is matched (neighbour colour is different from mine), the cell shouldn't be filled.

My question are:
1) Is there a better way to check if target square is viable for colour-filling?

2) If there is, how do I handle clicks on new cells correctly?

```js
function checkNeighbourTiles(aX, aY) {
  var coords = [
    [(aX - 1), (aY - 1)],
    [(aX - 1), (aY)],
    [(aX - 1), (aY + 1)],
    [(aX), (aY - 1)],
    [(aX), (aY + 1)],
    [(aX + 1), (aY - 1)],
    [(aX + 1), (aY - 1)],
    [(aX + 1), (aY + 1)]
  ]

  for (i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    var x = coords[i][0]
    var y = coords[i][1]
    var b = cells[x][y]
  }
}
```

My code so far - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f40afjdt/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the complexity and performance constraints. As you have done a direct lookup table is about as efficient as can be for a simple grid lookup, though instead of creating the lookup array each time just create an offsets array once.

```
// an array of offset coordinates in pairs x,y 8 pairs skipping the center
const NEIGHBOURS = [-1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];

const GIRD_SIZE = 10; // 10 by ten grid
function checkNeighbourTiles(x,y){
    var lx, ly, cellResult;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < 16){  // check for each offset
        lx = x + NEIGHBOURS[i++]; // get the x offset
        ly = y + NEIGHBOURS[i++]; // get the y offset
        // ensure you are inside the grid
        if( ly >= 0 && ly < GRID_SIZE && lx >= 0 && lx < GRID_SIZE ){
             cellResult = cell[lx][ly];
             // do what is needed with the result;
        }
    }
}
```

For the type of 2D array that is about simplest way to do it.

The alternative is a linked array were each cell holds and array of references to the neighbouring cells.
Thus (and with simplicity in mind) just the top left right and bottom. Then each cell would look like

```
cell = {
    top : undefined,
    left : undefined,
    right : undefined,
    bottom : undefined,
    ... other data
}
```

Then when you add the cell you set the references to the appropriate cells

```
// first add all the cells to the array 
// then for each cell call this
function AddCell(cell,x,y){
    cell.top = cells[x][y-1];
    cell.left = cells[x-1][y];
    cell.right = cells[x+1][y];
    cell.bottom = cells[x][y+1];
    // also the cells you just reference should also reference back
    // where top refs botton and left refs right and so fourth.
    cells.top.bottom = cell;
    cells.bottom.top = cell;
    cells.left.right = cell;
    cells.right.left = cell;

}
```

Then at any point if you want to find which cell is above

```
//x and y are the cell
var cellAbove = cell[x][y].top;
```

This method has many advantages when you start getting complex linking, like dead cells, or skipping cells, or even inserting cells so that you change the topology of the grid.

You can also do complex searches like two left one down

```
resultCall = cell[x][y].left.left.bottom; // returns the cell two left one down
```

But it is a pain to maintain the links as there is a lot of extra code involved so for a simple 2D grid your method is the best.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way for selecting squares might be using loops:

```
function (x, y){
    var coords = [];
    for(i = (x-1); i < (x+2); i++){
        for(j = (y-1); j < j (y+2); j++){
            coords.push([i, j]);
        }
    }

    //rest of the code
}
```

If you check the square at [0, 0], this code will search for a square at [-1, -1]. You're gonna need some serious if statements for filtering out the proper squares.

Likewise, if you have a 9x9 grid and you search for [8, 8], the code will look for the [9, 9] square eventually and go out of bounds.

Comment: well, the goal of the game is to connect all colours in the grid with as little cells as possible, while only same colour cells can touch.

Right now, I'm trying to handle click in target cell where I need to check if its neighbours are white or same colour( cell can be filled with colour)
or there are some other colours ( cell has to stay white)

I now about [-1,-1] but right now, I'm focusing on that handle.

Comment: Updated my answer to better help you.